# Vs code remote Ssh Connection issue

Tags: c#, linux, visual-studio-code, ssh, vscode-remote-ssh

I have been using VS Code and connecting remotely from home on my company computer to our Centos System via using SmarTTy. But I want to use VS code Remote SSH instead of SmarTTy due to the fact that SmarTTy doesn't have a good UI and I think it's obsolete. I faced some problems when I have created connection. I am sharing my conf. file

```
  Host app-ff
    HostName app-ff
    User cayhan
    IdentityFile C:\Users\cayhan\.ssh\id_rsa
```

I click 'Connect to Host Current Window' and ask me operating system (linux,windows,macos) and after that ask me password. Although everything is correct I can't access it with VSCode  and get error `'Could not establish connection . Permission denied'`

How can I solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

Windows has CLI ssh client now. You can open terminal in VS code and use

`ssh -i id_rsa username@IP`

Comment: Thank your quick response but it didn't solve my problem. As you advise, firstly, I have opened my Terminal in Vs Code and wrote the command that you advise me. After that, the system asked me password many times. Even though the password that I enter is correct, I got the message 'permission denied'

Comment: Did you type password of machine you are connecting to or you are typing your host machine's password(you are supposed to type password of machine you are connecting to)

Comment: I typed my host machine's user password given to me by my system administrator. By the way, if you know any program or extension that I can use instead of this, I can try it to use